# Exclude item from Sum formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create a formula where I sum the picked quantities for lines that have a line number but exclude the lines that don't have a line number. So I would want to see

```
Line#   shipqty
1          10
           10
2          10
```

---

My total should be 20.

So I'm trying to do sum(shipqty) where line#>0 but I can't figure out how to do this in Crystal.

Answer (score 0):

you can use running total.

1. In field to summarize take `Shipqty`.
2. In evaluate use option `formula`, In that write below condition.

   ```
    if(Line#>0)
    then true
    else false
   ```
3. In reset use option `never`.